# iCarousel - numberOfItemsInCarousel: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, icarousel

I'm trying to implement an iCarousel within a detailedView using a storyboard.

LocationDetailViewController.h

```
@interface LocationDetailViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel;
```

Storyboard:

The iCarousel is a View

dataSource -> View

delegate -> View

carouel -> Location Detai...

When I click from the tableview to the detail view where the carousel is located I get an error, before the .m is called (tested with NSLOG).

I receive this error:

```
-[UIView numberOfItemsInCarousel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb3134c0
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfItemsInCarousel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb3134c0'
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You have to set the data source and delegate to a class that actually implements those methods.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you explain exactly what you mean? thanks

Comment: You set the data source to a `UIView`. You need to set it to your `LocationDetailViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the icarousel delegate methods.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
     return [array count];
}
```

Refer this,

http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/how-to-use-icarousel-view-controller-in-ios/

Hope it helps.